# Strange filtering failure on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Recently, I wanted to develop a simple table filtering web application since I find the universities course selection page non-functional and hard to browse some courses which meet specific criterion. Thus, I wrote some code for the desired functionality:)

I'm new to javascript and this filtering-web-page is my first tiny project that contains javascript code. I, of course, used JQuery in the process, version 1.8.3.

My page layout is as follows:

4 filters with the functions

1. Course Code -- when selected, using AJAX, the table from the original source is fetched to the below of the filter div (just a huge `<table>` element).
2. Course Day -- when selected, the rows that do not contain that day are hidden.
3. Course Hour -- just like 2.
4. Major Restriction -- here is the problematic filter. First lets take a look at the tables structure.

[image: how table looks]

This screenshot is from the original source. Now that you see how major restriction column is filled, lets talk about the filter.

Here is the screenshot of my page:
[image: filter overview]

The first 3 selections work perfectly. Here is the js code to give you an idea. Below is the day filter.

```
$('#gunler').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "Seçiniz/Select") { //if an option for gunler (days) is selected
        $(".dersprg tr").show(); //show all rows first
        applyFilter(); //apply previously selected filters (hours, major restriction)
        $(".dersprg tr td:nth-child(6):missing('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent().hide(); //hide row that dont 
        $(".dersprg td:contains('CRN')").parent().show(); //show the header of the table  //contain selected
    } //option
    else { //if the option is "defaulted"
        $(".dersprg td").parent().show(); //show all rows
        applyFilter(); //apply previously selected filters
        $(".dersprg td:contains('CRN')").parent().show(); //show header of the table
    }
});
```

Well, major restriction filter has the same structure yet it produces some strange outputs. For example, when BLGE is chosen from the dropdown, the filter works fine. However when MAT is chosen, even though there is one course that is opened just for MAT students, the filter hides that row as well. Same goes for some BLG courses as well. There are 3-4 courses which has the major restriction as just "BLG" and when I chose BLG from the dropdown, other courses that contain BLG among other majors are shown, however some rows that only has BLG as major restriction are hid. I double checked everything and I appear to somehow miss the malfunctioning point.

The strange part is when I work the same code from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WbppU/1/), **it works just fine!** 
This is the jsfiddle code:

```
$.expr[':'].missing = function (elem, index, match) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || Sizzle.getText([elem]) || "").indexOf(match[3]) == -1;
}
$(".dersprg tr").show();
$(".dersprg tr td:nth-child(12):missing('MAT')").parent().hide();
$(".dersprg td:contains('CRN')").parent().show();
```

The html code is the original source I showed you earlier and the result is the single row that is filtered correctly!

[image: jsfiddle]

However, on localhost or the webpage the codes do not work as desired. I am using Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312.56 m. I checked the filter from Mozilla Firefox as well, but the result was the same.

Can you tell me what goes wrong and how I can correct it?

**Some additional info I thought it would be useful:**

I used a function called `applyFilter()`, here is the body of it:

```
function applyFilter() {
    if ($('#saatler').val() != "Seçiniz/Select") {
        $(".dersprg tr:missing('" + $('#saatler').val() + "')").hide();
    }
    if ($('#bolumler').val() != "Seçiniz/Select") {
        $(".dersprg tr:missing('" + $('#bolumler').val() + "')").hide();
    }
    if ($('#gunler').val() != "Seçiniz/Select") {
        $(".dersprg tr:missing('" + $('#gunler').val() + "')").hide();
    }
}
```

Here is how the options are created for major restriction filter:

```
<option selected value="Seçiniz/Select">Seçiniz/Select</option>
    <?php
    $bolumler = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('bolumler.csv'));
    foreach ($bolumler as $bolum)
        echo '<option value="' . $bolum . '">' . $bolum . '</option>';
    ?>
</select>
```

and the content of "bolumler.csv"

> BIO, BIOE, BLG, BLGE, CEV, CEVE, CHZ, CHZE, DEN, DENE, DUIK, EHB,
>   EHBE, ELE, ELH, ELK, ELKE, END, ENDE, EUT, EUTE, FIZ, FIZE, GEM, GEME,
>   GEMK, GEO, GEOE, GID, GIDE, GMIK, ICM, IML, IMLE, INS, INSE, ISL,
>   ISLE, JDF, JEF, JEFE, JEO, JEOE, KIM, KIME, KMM, KMME, KON, KONE, MAD,
>   MADE, MAK, MAKE, MAT, MATE, MET, METE, MIM, MIME, MTO, MTOE, PEM,
>   PEME, PET, PETE, SBP, SBPE, TEK, TEKE, TEL, THO, UCK, UCKE, UZB, UZBE

Comment: Can you post a link to your jsFiddle?

Comment: Thank you for editing, pete:) [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WbppU/1/) is the jsfiddle link. As you see the filter works perfectly. I think the problem might be about the csv file in some way but that doesnt make sense either. Im lost please help me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is works in the fiddle and not on your page is that `Sizzle` is not defined on your page (but it is defined in the fiddle). You could include `Sizzle.js` seperately, or use `$.find` as jQuery exposes the Sizzle selector engine via `$.find`, or you could use a simpler method for getting the text to compare for your `:missing` selector (such as `$(elem).text()` below).

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    "missing": function (elem, index, match) {
        var text = $(elem).text(),
            test = new RegExp('\\b' + match[3] + '\\b'); // test on word boundaries
        return !text.match(test);
    }
});
```

I took the liberty of changing the the comparison to use word boundaries as it will distinguish between cells containing substrings.

As an example, if I'm trying to find cells that are missing `FIZ` your current `:missing` selector will not distinguish between cells that contain `FIZ` and `FIZE` (as `FIZE` contains `FIZ`). By changing the selector to find the token between word boundaries, this is no longer a problem.

I also took a little liberty in refactoring your code and switching over to jQuery AJAX instead of your custom AJAX routine (as it seemed simpler).

Using the console, I was able to get the following code to work as expected in Chrome (Version 24.0.1312.57 m):

```
//Gun Saat ve Bolum Filtreleri
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var fetchPage = function fetchPage(fb) {
        var t = $('#table');
        if (!fb) {
            t.empty();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                "url": "http://ilbeyli.fast-page.org/ITUDersProg/fetch.php",
                "data": {
                    "url": "http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb=" + fb
                },
                "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    t.html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        $('#saatler, #gunler, #bolumler').val('Seçiniz/Select');
    }, changeHandler = function changeHandler(e) {
        var self = $(this),
            dersprg = $('.dersprg'),
            gun = $('#gunler').val() !== 'Seçiniz/Select' ? $('#gunler').val().trim() : '',
            saat = $('#saatler').val() !== 'Seçiniz/Select' ? $('#saatler').val().trim() : '',
            bolum = $('#bolumler').val() !== 'Seçiniz/Select' ? $('#bolumler').val().trim() : '',
            gunRows = $(".dersprg tbody tr td:nth-child(6)").filter(":missing('" + gun + "')").parents('tr'),
            saatRows = $(".dersprg tbody tr td:nth-child(7)").filter(":missing('" + saat + "')").parents('tr'),
            bolumRows = $(".dersprg tbody tr td:nth-child(12)").filter(":missing('" + bolum + "')").parents('tr');
        dersprg.find('tbody tr').show();    // show all rows
        if (gun) {
            gunRows.hide();     // hide rows that do not contain `gun`
        }
        if (saat) {
            saatRows.hide();    // hide rows that do not contain `saat`
        }
        if (bolum) {
            bolumRows.hide();   // hide rows that do not contain `bolum`
        }
        // show the header rows
        dersprg.find('td:contains("CRN")').parents('tr').show();
    };
    $('#derskodu').change(function (e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        fetchPage(val);
    });
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        "missing": function (elem, index, match) {
            var text = $(elem).text(),
                test = new RegExp('\\b' + match[3] + '\\b'); // test on word boundaries
            return !text.match(test);
        }
    });
    $('#gunler, #saatler, #bolumler').change(changeHandler);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your answer, pete. I will have some questions tho. I was aware of the problem about the missing selector as you mentioned the FIZ exmples. I started to test your solution by including only sizzle.js as i think how you mentioned, however it had no effects at all. Should i include more of the contents of the zip which is found [on their web page](http://sizzlejs.com/)? I'd first rather go for the simplest solution for the simplicity sake, since im very new to the subject. So 1st attempt was failure, any suggestions before i proceed to other workarounds you told?

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli: The only file you would normally include would be `Sizzle.js` as that defines the `Sizzle` function in a global scope. I'd go with the `$(elem).text()` fix, unless you find that it doesn't work for all cases. Using the console, I was able to temporarily override your functions by substituting the giant code block above and while your functions were overridden, the page behaved as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that changing the `:missing` selector code also causes all my rows to get hidden even though it works fine in jsfiddle. This strikes me as a missing include file but i cannot be sure. Do you have any idea about why i get this result when i change my code as you suggested? Also additional question, i could not get the exact point on which the `:missing` filter fails on single valued major restriction columns. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: unaccepted the answer because i think i came across a bug. Try filtering the table as follows: `Course Code BLG, Major Restriction: KON, Course Day: Sali`. It hides the rows which has Sali as a day in them. The day filter is bugged when `Sali` and `Carsamba` options are chosen.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli: Please update your page with my script above so I can debug it properly. I cannot do this locally as your server does not allow me to access your fetch script ("Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"). I have copied the table generated by selecting "BLG" from `#derskodu` into a local copy and my script works perfectly on the local copy.

Comment: I actually was talking about your script above, the two options (Salı and Çarşamba) i mentioned earlier seem not to work on my local copy for the time being. I couldnt figure out what is wrong. By the way, do you have any idea about why `:missing` selector fails to work properly on single valued Major Restriction entries?

Comment: oh, now i get your message completely, [here](http://ilbeyli.fast-page.org/ITUDersProg/Debug/) is the debug site i uploaded for you. I made some changes though, I made a js file that contains the js code which you can access throuth this [link](http://ilbeyli.fast-page.org/ITUDersProg/Debug/js/filters.js). Thank you for your time:)